# Upgrading to magento 1.9.1.0 from 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento

What is the best way to upgrade magento to the latest version.

I noticed in magento connect that there are many 1.9.1.0 upgrades available. Are these at all related to the new magento version?

Is the only way to upgrade to go through all the files 1 by 1 and file compare?

Answer (score 1):

**What is the best way ?**

It's depending your catalog. If you have large amount of catalogs(i.e 2000 products) then  manual upgrade is best. If your catalog size is small then go for **magento-connect** .

And according to your second question, those packages are upgrades for the next version. You have to install those packages also.

And according to your 3rd question. we wont upgrade go through all the files 1 by 1 and file compare.

Download the latest version of magento (*say magento-new*), put it in your root directory and connect database of your current magento version (say *magento-old*) with *magento-new*. For this just copy local.xml file from  *magento-old/app/etc/* to  *magento-new/app/etc/*. And change the base_url to  *magento-new* path in `core_config_data` table.

Finally run the  *magento-new* from your browser. It will take some time. wait for this.At last run the indexing process. That's it.